# Using Firebase push() to create a list

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the reference I created to my Firebase database

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

However, when I try to use this as the base_url for a push(), I get this error:

```
Value of type 'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'push'
```

I tried to change my base_url to this:

```
let ref = Firebase.database().ref()
```

But then I get

```
Module 'Firebase' has no member 'database'
```

Here's my Podfile. Am I missing something? I have imported Firebase at the top of my file.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ValleybrookMessenger' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for ValleybrookMessenger

    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  target 'ValleybrookMessengerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ValleybrookMessengerUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Sounds like an answer @mjr! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift doesn't have a `push()` method, so the equivalent you probably want is [`childByAutoId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a18f449729a922397587a9f0c5e0ab812).

The first way you created the reference is correct:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a much more intuitive method name anyway

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if methods had the same name across all platforms. One day perhaps!

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't provide push method as javascript does, but you can perform similar action by following code

```
let ref = Database.database().reference("Items")
var key = ref.childByAutoId().key as? String ?? ""
ref.child(key).setValue(["Item_Name" : name])
```

In javascript push method automatically generates a unique key but in swift you can generate by

```
var key = ref.childByAutoId().key as? String ?? ""
```

which you can add to reference as a child and setValue inside that key.